pull value from Key Vault to use in local dev web.config
I want to store a secret in Azure Key vault, pull into the application settings in an app service (which is working) and when I run the app I can retrieve the data.
Now I want to obtain this value in my local development using visual studio
Thanks to help from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEaCnhvggz0
If you skip to the 9 min mark I was able to

link the KV to the app service using managed identity
store a value in my KV
pull the value from KV and use as an app setting (on the app service) - which is then displayed as a Key Vault Reference in the source


Using the value for this as:
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://keyVaultName/secrets/SecretName/1121283182091283/)


Then reference Secret_Value in code using:
in my web.config:
<add key="Secret_Value" value="localDev" />

C#
var Secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Secret_Value"];

which when I run the app locally on VS this returns 'localDev' but correctly when I run on app service this returns the value from the KV
How do I grab the value on my local dev? because obv I cant do this:
<add key="Secret_Value" value="@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://keyVaultName/secrets/SecretName/1121283182091283/)" />

Is this possible? I know I can add KeyVault as  Nuget package and obtian with something like:
   var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultURL), new DefaultAzureCredential());
        var secret = client.GetSecret(CRM_Secret_KeyVaultName);

but I dont want this.
I want to pull the value from the local webconfig directly from the KV, is this possible? Without writing any extra code? thanks for any replies

If you want to get a value from KeyVault you will at the very least need to authenticate

as in from C#? what do you mean sorry?

In VS you need to log in with the credentials you use for Azure and this will give you the right credentials,  however, there may be other settings \ contraints that you will have put in place in Azure.
Use DefaultCredntials and you should be fine as this will cycle through all possible until you get the authentication

Using keyvault with reference in local is not possible.

Thanks for the replies… so is there anyway to do it from local without writing code?


so is there anyway to do it from local without writing code?


We cannot directly bind the Key Vault reference in the local configuration file.

I have tried to set and retrieve the secret with reference in local.


You can see it is not working.


When you configure Key Vault from Connected Service locally, by default it installs the related NuGet Packages to access the Key Vault (by default it is the only option available locally).


In this case you can separate the local and production configurations.

You can store the secret value directly in the local configuration file (Web.config).


OR
You can set the secret values in secrets.xml.


And can continue with the key vault reference in the deployed App Service Application settings (which you have already done) without any code.

AFAIK, you can retrieve the Azure Key Vault secrets either with code or with Key Vault Reference in the deployed Azure App Service only.
Thanks @RyanHill-MSFT for the comment.

Key Vault is a hosted service and therefore can't be used in local development. It is recommended that development secrets be used.

You can also refer the GitHub link which explains the same.

Thank you for taking the time to write all that out, I have awarded the answer because you have answered my Q with how this is possible but now I have a new issue, if you have time please see my new Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78439877/the-configbuilder-azurekeyvault-failed-while-processing-the-configuration-sect thanks again

Sure will check and let you know.
