The configBuilder 'AzureKeyVault' failed while processing the configuration section 'appSettings'
Thanks to @Harshitha for pointing me in the right path, using connected services in VS 2019 to connect to a keyVault which can then ref values using appSettings.
To test this I created a new dummy app using a .Net 4.8 framwork application in C#
I have followed this clip:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7EPrlpPqXw
Basically, use connected services to connect to your key vault.
This will include the following in your web.config file:
 <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <configBuilders>
        <builders>
          <add name="AzureKeyVault" vaultName="RealKeyVaultName" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </builders>
      </configBuilders>
      <appSettings configBuilders="AzureKeyVault">
       <!-- Value added by me -->
        <add key="secretInKV" value="dummyValue" />
     </appSettings>
    </configuration>

So basically creating a connection to KV using configSection and configBuilders
In code I can then say
var secretValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secretInKV"];

and this correctly returns the value stored in my KV, (not dummyValue from the above app settings) which is all working fine.
However when I try to add this to my real application I get an error loading:
Parser Error Message: The configBuilder 'AzureKeyVault' failed while processing the configuration section 'appSettings'.: Error in Configuration Builder 'AzureKeyVault'::GetValue(secretInKV)

The stack trace errors show:
[SocketException (0x2746): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]
[IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.]
[WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.]
[RequestFailedException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.]
[AggregateException: Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy.]
[Exception: Error in Configuration Builder 'AzureKeyVault'::GetValue(secretInKV)]

To test my connection to KV In code I can say:
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultURL), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var secret = client.GetSecret(secretInKV);

and as all of the depenedencies where added when using the connected service I am able to retrieve the value from KV, but I want to get it from app settings
if I remove
configBuilders="AzureKeyVault"

from
 <appSettings configBuilders="AzureKeyVault">

the application loads, why is this causing an issue please?
I have read similar posts online but was not able to solve,
I am properly connected else I wouldnt be able to get the value with the above mentioned C# code, so why is this causing an issue please?
thank you for any replies
I have matched the Nuget packages in the new dummy app I have created against my actual application and still this issue is happening

Are you behind a web proxy?

Even I am getting the same error in my sample App.Testing from my end will let you know If I found any sol.

The issue seems to be with the Credentials

I striped down the project to find the problem.
The problem was a httpRunTime tag in my config which was pointing to a targetFramework of 4.7, (updating my project to 4.8 didnt update all the references) this needed changing to match the actual framework which is 4.8

I have tried the same code configuration with the same Key Vault in 2 different environments.

Worked with basic sample template in both the systems.

System 1 :

I have sync issues in Visual Studio with the ID which I have access to in Key Vault.



I have multiple accounts registered in my Visual Studio, resulting in sync issue(sso).

Got the below error
The configBuilder 'AzureKeyVault' failed while processing the configuration section 'appSettings'.: Error in Configuration Builder 'AzureKeyVault'::GetValue(SampleSecret)



Click on the Click here to show additional error information: to get the detailed error.

The error is related to Credentials. App is failing to retrieve the Login credentials.

If you remove  configBuilders="AzureKeyVault" from App settings, the app will be up and run but it will not communicate with the mentioned configuration Builder to fetch the secrets.

Make sure the Visual Studio is logged in with the proper credentials as shown below.


Check the Azure Service Authentication => Account Selection in Visual Studio => Tools => Options .


Check if your Visual Studio has any updates.

System 2:
Visual Studio Account Settings

Output:


thanks for taking the time to respond, the authentication was not the problem, an reference that was poiting to an older version of .Net framework was. Thanks again

Ok..I faced the authentication issue..Glad you resolved it.
